# Django overriding ModelAdmin classes with a function requiring Model name

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my `admin.py`, I have a lot of `ModelAdmin` classes and I want them to all override a function, `has_module_permission`. I want to base the module permission off of the user's permissions for the model corresponding to the `ModelAdmin`, and to do that I need to know the model name in order to run `request.user.has_perm('app.add_<model>')` or something similar.

I think an easy way of doing this is to create a class that has this function which is somehow able to get the model name, and then have each of the `ModelAdmin` classes inherit from that. The problem is that I don't know how to access the model's name from `ModelAdmin`. What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the the model's name from `ModelAdmin` you can simply do the following: `self.model.__name__`